# Rails 4 log interleaved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4's production log file, I see requests are logged together, not one after one.... How could I fix this issue??

Example Log

```
Started GET "/cars" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-25 08:44:54 -0700
Started GET "/cars" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-25 08:44:54 -0700 
Rendered index.html 
Rendered index.html
```

I want it to be like this

```
Started GET "/cars" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-25 08:44:54 -0700
Rendered index.html 
Started GET "/cars" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-25 08:44:54 -0700 
Rendered index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it's a logging issue so much as an accurate representation of what's happening. If 2 requests occur at the *exact same time* (ie. `2013-09-25 08:44:54 -0700`), then neither will render until the other has started. Make sense?